# How is the host/host instance determined when you remotely deploy a BizTalk solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment

How is the host/host instance determined when you remotely deploy a BizTalk 2010 solution from Visual Studio?

I encountered an error when deploying BizTalk solution from Visual Studio to a remote machine, which I tracked back to the remote server not having a specific host/host instance, that was present on the local machine.

But I don't know of anywhere in the solution where the host/host instance is specified?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't.

There is no option in Visual Studio to set the Host for a particular artifact, just the Application, which has nothing to do with the host.

When you Deploy an app for the first time, you have to bind each Orchestration manually.  When you redeploy, the Deployment Driver keeps some 'hidden' binding files it uses to reapply the bindings after Deployment, that's why the Host and Port Bindings stick.

However, you can't Deploy to a remote machine so I'm not sure how to address the second item.

Answer (score 0):

As boatseller pointed out, deploying to a remote server using Visual Studio is not supported.
Options to deploy to a BizTalk server where you don't have Visual Studio are.

1. [Create a MSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577804.aspx) from the local BizTalk server where the application is deployed and Import and run the MSI on the target BizTalk Server.
2. Use scripts such as Powershell, MSBuild & Wix to deploy the DLLs and import the artefacts to target BizTalk server.

In fact the [BizTalk Deployment Framework](http://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/) uses a combination of the above to help automate it.